# MASM: Check if 4 chars are a palindrom

Tags: assembly, masm

I input four ASCII-chars: `ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4`.

I want to check if the 4-letter-word forms a palindrom.

The algorithm is correct, but it won't compile. Any ideas why?

```
;
; isPalindrom.asm 
;
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 100h
    .DATA
    ch1 DB ? ;var dec
    ch2 DB ? ;var dec
    ch3 DB ? ;var dec
    ch4 DB ? ;var dec
PrintUSER DB 13,10
         DB 'Pls enter 4 chars:',13,10,'$' 
         ;Print 4 chars string

PaliExists DB 13,10
         DB 'Palindrome permutation exists',13,10,'$'
         ;Print msg that pali exists

PaliNOTExists DB 13,10
         DB 'There is no possible solution',13,10,'$'
         ;Print msg that pali does not exist

     .CODE
ProgStart:
     MOV AX,@DATA             ; DS can be written to only through a register
     MOV DS,AX                ; Set DS to point to data segment

     MOV AH,9
     MOV DX, Offset PrintUSER
     INT 21h 

     MOV AH,1 
     INT 21h                  ; Input to ch1
     MOV ch1,AL

     MOV AH,1
     INT 21h                  ; Input to ch2
     MOV ch2,AL

     MOV AH,1
     INT 21h                  ; Input to ch3
     MOV ch3,AL

     MOV AH,1
     INT 21h   
     MOV ch4,AL      ; Input to ch4
     ;////////////////////////////////

     CMP ch1, ch2 ; Compare ch1,ch2
     JE checkThreeFour ; jump to label checkTwoThree
     JMP Skip1 ;Skip compare ch3,ch4

     checkThreeFour: ;label
     CMP ch3, ch4 ; Compare ch3,ch4
     JE Exists ; Jump to Exists
     JMP notExists

     Skip1:
     CMP ch1, ch3 ;Compare ch1,ch3
     JE checkTwoFour ;Jump
     JMP Skip2:

     checkTwoFour:
     CMP ch2, ch4 ;Compare ch2,ch4
     JE Exists ; Jump to Exists
     JMP notExists

     Skip2:
     CMP ch1, ch4 ;Compare ch1,ch4
     JE checkTwoThree ;Jump
     JMP notExists 

    checkTwoThree: 
     CMP ch2, ch3 ;Compare ch2,ch3
     JMP Exists ; Jump to Exists
     JMP notExists

Exists: ;print message for Existing pali
    MOV AH,9 
    MOV DX, Offset PaliExists 
    INT 21h
    JMP DisplayGreeting

notExists: ; print messasge palindrom does not exist
    MOV AH,9
    MOV DX, Offset PaliNOTExists
    INT 21h


DisplayGreeting:
     MOV AH,9                         ; Set print option for int 21h
     INT 21h                          ; Print  chosen message
     MOV AH,4Ch               ; Set terminate option for int 21h
     INT 21h                  ; Return to DOS (terminate program)
    END ProgStart
```

Comment: downvoted for a giant block of code with no mention of which line had the error, or what the error message is.  If you're going to post a "fix my compile error" question, at least put the compile error in the question so future people searching on that error message might find this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing two memory operands in your

```
CMP chX, chY ;Compare ch2,ch3
```

instructions. On Intel ISA, you cannot do that. One argument must always be a register, see for [CMP here](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMP.html).

So the solution would be to `MOV` one argument into a register first and then apply `CMP`.

P.S.: A simple solution to check if a 4-char-string is a palindrome would be:

```
mov eax, dword ptr [string]
mov edx, eax
bswap edx
cmp eax, edx
je palindrome
no_palindrome:
...
jmp end
palindrome:
...
end:
```